# How I can do a confirmation window?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to create a confirmation window when I fill in a form.

Right now, I fill in the form and if the form is valid, the entity is persisted and returned a view with my entity as a parameter. But this isn't what I want.

If the form is valid I don't want to persist the entity. If it's valid, would have to show a view using my parameter(entity) and then if my user clicks the button to confirm, persist the entity and redirect to other view. If my user clicks the button to return, I use the JavaScript function: `javascript:history.back(1)`.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to store your bound entity in session (a flash) and retrieve it after confirmation for persistence.

In your "saveForm" action:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $myEntity = $form->getData();
    $this->get('session')->setFlash('my_entity', $myEntity);

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Controller:confirmation.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $myEntity
    ));
}
```

And in your "confirmSave" action:

```
$myEntity = $this->get('session')->getFlash('my_entity');
$this->em->persist($myEntity);
$this->em->flush();
```

It's just a basic example an it needs to be adaped to your project.

Comment: Doing this, the EntityManager try to persist a null entity and display this exception: NULL
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException